# How to simulate user action on kivy widget ? (click on a button by example)

Tags: python, events, kivy, widget

I want to simulate the user action and after looking in the doc, I saw the `Clock.schedule_once(my_callback, 1)`.

.

**Question:** Is this the only way to do it ? I would have prefered something like `my_button.press()`.

.

I want to press the button and then, it will call `my_callback`, I don't want to directly call `my_callback`.

*(Because if I do this and my callback evolve, I lost the good reference)*

PS: I saw that there was the possibility to use `Clock.create_trigger(my_callback)` but it didn't seems to be the good solution here.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

KV_APP = '''
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        id: my_button
        text: "Click on me"
'''

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV_APP)
        self.screen.ids["my_button"].bind(on_press=self.on_button_click)
        event = Clock.schedule_once(self.on_button_click, 1)
        return self.screen

    def on_button_click(self, instance):
        print("hello there !")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `Event` and dispatch it. Here is an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.input.providers.mouse import MouseMotionEvent
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def mydispatchAnEvent(self, *args):
        # create and dispatch a fake event
        touch = MouseMotionEvent(None, 123, (123, 456))  # args are device, id, spos
        touch.button = 'left'
        touch.pos = (321, 654)
        self.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch)


theRoot = Builder.load_string('''
MyBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Button below should demonstrate receiving touch event'
    Button:
        text: 'Waiting for event'
        on_press: print('touched')
''')


class EventDispatcherPlayApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(theRoot.mydispatchAnEvent, 2)
        return theRoot

EventDispatcherPlayApp().run()
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this tomorrow, I have an aws api gateway to finish, thanks for the answer !

Comment: I used this answer to automate some testing of my app. I know the kivy unit tests could be another way to do it, but still I'm surprised there aren't more questions and answers on the topic.