# Simulate key press kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Is there any way to simulate key press in Kivy, I have seen some SO questions about simulating [mouse clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350205/how-to-simulate-user-action-on-kivy-widget-click-on-a-button-by-example), but not about keyboard press.

I am aware of events, but I need a way to generate a key press.
Thank you