# Simulate touch_up event in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, mousemotionevent

To simulate a touch_down event I followed the code in this post [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350205/how-to-simulate-user-action-on-kivy-widget-click-on-a-button-by-example/66353082#66353082?newreg=76e7e12cda784c949d4655d085f2c5b8)

However it does not work for touch_up. it seems that more information must be passed to the mousemotionevent in order for the tocuh_up event to be processed.

Any ideas?

This code can simulate A touch_down event on tab2. But the tabs does not get switched because it does need a touch_up event that I am sending but it does not work.

```
enter code here

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.input.providers.mouse import MouseMotionEvent

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTabs:
        id: android_tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)


<Tab>:

    MDLabel:
        id: label
        text: "Tab 0"
        halign: "center"
'''


class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    '''Class implementing content for a tab.'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.root.ids.android_tabs.add_widget(Tab(title=f"Tab {i}"))
        Window.bind(on_motion=self.on_motion)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dispatchTouchDown, 2)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dispatchTouchUp, 2.5)

    def on_motion(self, obj, tevent, touch):
        print (tevent, touch.sx*Window.width, touch.sy*Window.height)


    def on_tab_switch(
        self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):
        instance_tab.ids.label.text = tab_text

    def dispatchTouchDown(self, *args):
        # create and dispatch a fake event
        touch = MouseMotionEvent(None, 0, (0, 0))  # args are device, id, spos
        touch.button = 'left'
        touch.pos = (130, 570)
        touch.x = touch.px = touch.ox = 130
        touch.y = touch.py = touch.oy = 570
        Window.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch)
        #This works

    def dispatchTouchUp(self, *args):
        # create and dispatch a fake event
        touch = MouseMotionEvent(None, 0, (0, 0))  # args are device, id, spos
        touch.button = 'left'
        touch.pos = (130, 570)
        touch.x = touch.px = touch.ox = 130
        touch.y = touch.py = touch.oy = 570
        Window.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch)
        #This does not work

Example().run()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.